# Returning data that came from Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, promise, bluebird

I'm creating a script which reads data from pdf in node, I'm using `pdf_text_extract`, and I'm trying to return the data with Bluebird.

Types.js:

```
var pdf = require('pdf');

var Types = {
    read: function(file, extension) {
        pdf.extract(file, function(error, data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
};

module.exports = Types;
```

The data is a [Function], this is clearly wrong.

Pdf.js:

```
var Promise             = require('bluebird');
var pdf_text_extract    = require('pdf-text-extract');

var Pdf = {
    extract: function(file, cb) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            if (reject) {
                console.log(reject);
            }

            pdf_text_extract(file, function(error, data) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }

                resolve(data);
            });
        });
    }
};

module.exports = Pdf;
```

I'm trying to access the data in other archive, which is calling the Types.js.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: i edit the question.

Comment: pdf_text_extract.read? even that would be wrong as the parameters won't make sense.

Comment: exactly. you are calling pdf_text_extract as if it were a function. 
big tip: don't be rude, you are asking for help.

Comment: Pay attention @WalterMacambira, read the question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `data` is not a function. The `cb` function you're passing is completely *ignored* and never executed, the log you are seeing is from `console.log(reject);` (as `reject` is always truthy).

Correct would be

```
var pdf = {
    extract: function(file) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            pdf_text_extract(file, function(error, data) {
                if (error) 
                    reject(error);
                else
                    resolve(data);
            });
        });
    }
};
var types = {
    read: function(file, extension) {
        return pdf.extract(file).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
        // returns a promise that fulfills with undefined once data or error are received
    }
};
```

Or much simpler

```
var pdf = {
    extract: Promise.promisify(pdf_text_extract)
};
```

Comment: Nice, thanks very much Bergi. But i have a question. I'm calling the types in other file, and i need return the data for this file, this is possible??

Comment: @AmandaFerrari: No, it's not, but you can return the promise for the data.

Comment: Bergi, but if i try to return the promise, the output will be something strange like: { _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _progressHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _settledValue: undefined }

Comment: Yes, that is what a Bluebird promise looks like in the console